# Redundant variable naming issue with purrr::map and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, scoping

I would guess that this is a basic issue that isn't specific to `purrr` at all, but it caught me off guard in this context. The general answer would be great if this isn't about how `purrr` and `dplyr` play together.

**I tried to name a variable I was "mapping" over the same as the variable in the d.f. I wanted to match, and it led to problems**. Can someone explain why my first attempt to generate pairwise differences fails?

It seems like a variable scoping issue or something with redundant names but I don't know exactly what is wrong. Obviously, I found a workaround.

Imagine I have data like `mydf` below and there are a lot of variables, and I want to compute the difference in the values of those variables between each pair of sites:

```
#four sites
site<-rep(c("j", "k", "l", "m"), 3)
#some measurment
val<-1:12
#some variable
vari<-c(rep(1,4), rep(2, 4), rep(3,4))
mydf<-data.frame(site, val, vari)


#compute pairwise differences between values at each site for each variable 
outp<-map_dfr(1:3, function(vari){
    dists<-as.numeric(dist(mydf %>% filter(vari==vari) %>% select(val), method="manhattan"))
    names(dists)<-c("jk","jl", "jm", "kl", "km", "lm" )
    dists
    return(data.frame(t(dists), vari=vari))

})
# looks like there was an issue with using "vari"
outp

#but use a different name for the same variable and it works fine
outp2<-map_dfr(1:3, function(a){
    dists<-as.numeric(dist(mydf %>% filter(vari==a) %>% select(val), method="manhattan"))
    names(dists)<-c("jk","jl", "jm", "kl", "km", "lm" )
    dists
    return(data.frame(t(dists), vari=vari))

})
outp2
```

**edit** as noted in comments and answer below, the issue here is in variable usage in `dplyr::filter` and not with `purrr`

Comment: `combn` might be handy here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! But what's actually _wrong_ with what I did to create outp?

Comment: Ah! What error did you get? Might be a(n)  NSE issue!

Comment: Could you see if doing as stated here solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945534/dplyr-and-non-standard-evaluation-nse You might need such "things" as `!!, enquo sym` from `rlang`.

Comment: I may be missing your point - but this looks like a scoping issue. `vari` in `filter` verb is being read as the column from `mydf` on both sides of the `==` operator, rather than the right hand side being the argument passed to your function

Comment: I think the discussion in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3840) is relevant and will be helpful.  Since `filter()` automatically evaluates in terms of the data frame, you need to use tidy evaluation here.  Like `filter(vari == !!vari)`

Comment: @NelsonGon, I think that SO post gets at the same point that aosmith pointed to (I think that discussion is easier to follow)... and thanks for the edit!. What's protocol here? Does one of you write out your comment as an answer, do we call my question a duplicate, do I delete? Thanks

Comment: Well, if you think it's a duplicate, it could be marked as so. Deleting it in my opinion is not very good as this question might be necessary in the future for me, you and everyone else. Different wording(s) of the same problem do help.

Comment: @Michael I think it would be useful for you to write up an answer from things you learned and how to solve the problem for posterity and then mark the question as solved.  I looked at the SO link but don't think I would have quickly understood the link between your issue and that issue so didn't mark as a duplicate.

Comment: I've added an answer below. However, I don't think that `output2 <- map_dfr(…)` is working the way it's supposed to. It's returning a dataframe with far too many rows. I think `vari = vari` needs to be `vari = a`.

Comment: @aosmith I think gersht wrote up a very nice answer and so I've accepted. Thanks to all here for excellent mentorship!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run some simplified code it might make sense. For example:

```r
# Remove the vector `vari` to avoid confusion.
rm(vari)

# Run using `map` and a simplified function.
map(1:3, function(vari) filter(mydf, vari==vari))
```

The above call to `map` returns a list of three dataframes, each identical to `mydf`:

```r
[[1]]
   site val vari
1     j   1    1
2     k   2    1
3     l   3    1
4     m   4    1
5     j   5    2
6     k   6    2
7     l   7    2
8     m   8    2
9     j   9    3
10    k  10    3
11    l  11    3
12    m  12    3

[[2]]
   site val vari
1     j   1    1
2     k   2    1
3     l   3    1
4     m   4    1
5     j   5    2
6     k   6    2
7     l   7    2
8     m   8    2
9     j   9    3
10    k  10    3
11    l  11    3
12    m  12    3

[[3]]
   site val vari
1     j   1    1
2     k   2    1
3     l   3    1
4     m   4    1
5     j   5    2
6     k   6    2
7     l   7    2
8     m   8    2
9     j   9    3
10    k  10    3
11    l  11    3
12    m  12    3
```

It's obvious that `filter(vari == vari)` is comparing `mydf$vari` with itself, which will simply return an exact copy of `mydf`. This is a good behavior because we always know what `filter` will compare. Try the same thing with a temporary variable `x`:

```r
map(1:3, function(x) filter(mydf, vari==x))
```

Which returns the expected subsets:

```r
[[1]]
  site val vari
1    j   1    1
2    k   2    1
3    l   3    1
4    m   4    1

[[2]]
  site val vari
1    j   5    2
2    k   6    2
3    l   7    2
4    m   8    2

[[3]]
  site val vari
1    j   9    3
2    k  10    3
3    l  11    3
4    m  12    3
```

This is basically what you did in your "workaround" – which I would describe as valid code using proper conventions, i.e. not a workaround at all.

aosmith already pointed out that you can use tidy evaluation. This is pretty neat, and it definitely has it's use cases, but I think it would reflect bad practice in this particular context. Using a temporary variable would make your code less ambiguous and thus more readable. It also makes sense because we are really dealing with two different things: `vari` is a vector containing the (repeated) values 1, 2, and 3 while `x` is in essence a temporary loop variable that is either 1 *or* 2 *or* 3, depending on the iteration.