# dplyr group_by and summarize with non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have this code:

```
> df<-data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,2), b=c(T,T,F,F,F,T))
> df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(trues=sum(b), falses=sum(!b))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
      a trues falses
  <dbl> <int>  <int>
1     1     2      1
2     2     1      2
```

and I want to use a string variable to give `b` (in a for loop, for example).  It's exactly like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945534/dplyr-and-non-standard-evaluation-nse) I think, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Some failed attempts:

```
var <- 'b'

df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize_(trues=sum(var), falses=sum(!var))
df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(trues=sum({{var}}), falses=sum(!{{var}}))
df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize_(trues=sum({{var}}), falses=sum(!{{var}}))
foo1 <- function(df, var) {
  df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(trues=sum({{var}}), falses=sum(!{{var}}))
}
foo1(df, 'b')
foo2 <- function(df, var) {
  var <- enquo(var)
  df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(trues=sum(!!var), falses=sum(! !!var))
}
foo2(df, 'b')
```

Perhaps I could use the `lazyeval` package in the other question, but I'd rather know how to do it with just the tidyverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, it is better to use `ensym` as we are passing a string.  Also, the `ensym` works with unquoted argument as well

```
foo2 <- function(df, var) {
   var <- ensym(var)
   df %>% 
         group_by(a) %>%
         summarize(trues=sum(!!var), 
                   falses=sum(! (!!var)))
  }
foo2(df, 'b')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      a trues falses
#* <dbl> <int>  <int>
#1     1     2      1
#2     2     1      2


foo2(df, b)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      a trues falses
#* <dbl> <int>  <int>
#1     1     2      1
#2     2     1      2
```

---

If the argument passed is an object, evaluate (`!!`) while passing into the function to avoid the literal evaluation

```
foo2(df, !!var)
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#      a trues falses
#* <dbl> <int>  <int>
#1     1     2      1
#2     2     1      2
```

Comment: Works! I'll accept when stackoverflow lets me (7 minutes). Can you say why the others didn't work?

Comment: And why it only works in a function? And (bonus) how I could get it to work without a function (since I'm just using it in a for loop)?

Comment: @dfrankow If you check `?enquo` `The defusing operators expr() and enquo() prevent the evaluation of R code. Defusing is also known as quoting, and is done in base R by quote() and substitute(). When a function argument is defused, R doesn't return its value like it normally would but it returns the R expression describing how to make the value. These defused expressions are like blueprints for computing values.`

Comment: @dfrankow outside the function you can use `quo` `sym` without the `en`

Comment: Oh wait, I can't quite accept. I want to use "var", not "b". It's a for loop, with "var" being set to each variable in turn.

Comment: accepted! bonus points if that could be done outside a function.

Comment: @dfrankow you meant `enquo/ensym` for those you need `quo/sym`.  Also, there are tidy select helpers i.e. `df %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise(across(var, ~ sum(.)))`